# Vishnu Yantra and other abstract symbolism

Tags: scripture, vishnu, yantra, numbers, abstract

Is there a Yantra or other abstract form of Vishnu I can draw for protective or devotional purposes, but others as well? Other examples are **numbers** and letters found in scripture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Narada Purana describes  Yantras for Narasimha, Krishna and various other forms of vishnu for protection and other purposes.

Naradapurana III.71.95

[image]

[image]

Narada Purana III.80.155

[image]

Comment: Beautiful and straightforward answer a good start to your HSE activity.